# Is it possible to hide drag handles in non-expanded gnome panel?

Tags: gnome-panel, dockbarx

I've just started using DockBarX in place of AWN, and I'm liking the simplicity of it. The one thing I've found that irritates me is the visible drag handles in the panel. (My awn setup had no panels.) Is there any setting that will hide them?

Here's what I'm talking about; outlined in red:

[image]

Comment: Not being familiar with DockBarX - are you sure those handles are from a gnome-panel? If so: no, there is no way to configure a gnome-panel to not show the drag handlers.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure they're from the panel. If you set a gnome panel to be non-expanded, you get the handles so you can drag it to a different position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, at least not with the standard gnome-panel.

There is a bug report with a patch for this: [#412975[image]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/412975).
It doesn't look like an option to hide the drag handles will ever be added to the standard gnome-panel though.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it probably wasn't (easily) possible, but figured I'd ask. I'm sure I'm not the only one who'd like the option to hide them.